# syntax error for ruby using array

Tags: ruby

I tried if I use 2*(2-1), that works, but if I need the value of x.(x.count/2), and then it said syntax error. how can I use the array correctly?

thanks!

```
x = ["2,", "5", "7", "10", "20", "30", "50", "90", "101", "120"]
x.(x.count/2)
```

NoMethodError: undefined method `call' for ["2,", "5", "7", "10", "20", "30", "50", "90", "101", "120"]:Array
    from (irb):10

Comment: @meagar this code is reproducible, remove your flag.

Comment: @stefan It's a reproducible syntax error due to using the wrong character. It's not a useful question, and a solution will not be helpful to anybody else.

Comment: @meager I believe this could be a common error (using object notation instead of array notation)

Comment: @ray what is `x.(x.count/2)` supposed to return?

Comment: @meagar I don't think you are right. This error is reproducible and I think it will be common for people coming from some other language. Problem here is that user uses wrong syntax for accessing array elements and indeed the error ruby shows is somewhat misdirecting at first glance

Comment: @IvayloStrandjev You keep saying "the error is reproducible". That's nonsense. You can hammer any string of gibberish into a Ruby interpreter to reproduce this error. Regardless, I don't care about the reproducibility of the problem; the second half of the close message says: **...or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers.**

Comment: @meagar what if you come from a language where a. (5) is the way to access sixth element of a? The ruby error will not help you much, either.

Comment: @IvayloStrandjev Then you should read a Ruby tutorial. You could make the same argument about *any* syntax element from *any* language. We don't need a million silly questions with every possible form of invalid Ruby syntax.

Comment: For a beginner it might not be obvious that `/` is message passing and not built in syntax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use brackets instead of parenthesis for an array.

```
 x = ["2,", "5", "7", "10", "20", "30", "50", "90", "101", "120"]
 x[x.count/2]
```

Comment: That should be `x[x.count/2]` (without the first dot)

Comment: yes, I tried x.[x.count/2]. still error. the correct one should x[x.count/2]. thanks so much, @Stefan!

Comment: Sorry missed that, updated answer

Answer (score 2):

I think you mean to call the `[]` operator. Instead you are using `()` to perform indexing on the array which results in calling `x.(5)` or `x(5)`. This operator is not defined for an array. You should instead write `x.[](x.count/2)` or more simply `x[x.count/2]`.

Comment: You *could* write `x.[](arg)`, but not `x.[arg]`

Comment: @Stefan yes, thank you

Comment: `x.(5)` is not equivalent to `x(5)`. The former invokes `x.call(5)` whereas the latter attempts to call a *method* `x` with argument `5`.

Comment: thanks @IvayloStrandjev !